# Can you change the default scale_x_datetime?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any way to override the default scale_x_datetime? I know I can add + scale_x_datetime(label = "format") to every plot.

I'm looking for a way to change/override the order of the current "smart" formatting globally. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own custom scale_x_datetime function and use this for all your plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
start <- ISOdate(2001, 1, 1, tz = "")
dat <- data.frame(day30  = start + round(runif(100, max = 30 * 86400)),
                 y = runif(100))

myDatetime <- function(..., labels = date_format("%d/%m")) {
  scale_x_datetime(..., labels = labels)
}
qplot(day30, y, data = dat) + myDatetime()
```